# Create task in windows task scheduler triggered by an event ID and task name

Tags: events, task, scheduler

I have a windows task scheduled to run dtexec and execute an ssis package. I would like to create another task to send an email once the task completes. I looked at the event filters while trying to create a new task, and I noticed that you can put the event ID, but not the actual task name. Is there anyway to tell the task scheduler which task I would like to link my new task to?